# How to use Spock in an OSGi environment?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, spock

I'm trying to include [spock-core-1.1-groovy-2.4](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/spockframework/spock-core/1.1-groovy-2.4/spock-core-1.1-groovy-2.4.jar) into my environment, but it seems it contains some statements in its MANIFEST.MF file, that are not quite legal, e.g. a dependency on `net.bytebuddy;version="[1.6.0,1)"` which gets me this error:

> Status ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository code=0 Range
>   minimum "1.6.0" is not less then range maximum "1.0.0" (inclusion is
>   required at both ends if the versions are equal)

...when I'm trying to include it into my eclipse repository. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No work around. That statement is illegal. You need to either fix the statement or use a different version of the bundle which a valid manifest.